# Align two items between image and ruler

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have a logo which is displaying properly and I want to have the Google Translate drop down display right below it then beside it with 20 pixels of space have my menu on the same line.  Then below these two items display a horizontal divider.  The main text shall display below the divider.

However, I am having trouble getting the Google Translate to display under the logo and the menu display next to it with some space between them:

- The horizontal line is showing above these two items instead of below
  them.
- Could not get the space between Google Translate and menu
- The Google Translate is overwritten the main text

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tapioca/ogzqLp0f/13/) to show the issue.

The main problem is with these two CSS item I believe but I have tried many variations and just couldn't get it to align properly.

```
/* PROBLEM IN THE FOLLOWING TWO CSS  */

#google-translate {
  left:10px;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  float:left;
  }
#header_right {
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
  padding-left:20px;
  }
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDITED:

Expected outcome would look like:

```
LOGO
Google Translate + 20px + Menu
Horizontal line
Main Text
```

Google Translate and the menu should sit on top of the horizontal line.

Comment: can you add a image of an expected output if possible using paint or diagram tool??

Comment: @Gowtham I have edited the issue above.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added the answer check it out

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of js fiddle , look into it

```
<div id="header_holder">
  <a href="/dev/index.htm" id="logo" title="Logo">Logo</a>

  <div id="header_right">
   <div id="google-translate">
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script>
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'en'
        }, 'google_translate_element');
      }

    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  </div>
  <div id="left20">
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
      <li><span class="dir">Menu A</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="dir">Menu B</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Menu C</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="rule">

</div>
<div>
  MAIN BODY TEXT 1
  <BR /> MAIN BODY TEXT 2
  <BR /> MAIN BODY TEXT 3
  <BR /> MAIN BODY TEXT 4
  <BR /> MAIN BODY TEXT 5
  <BR /> MAIN BODY TEXT 6
  <BR />
</div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eacnn958/

Check the above link

Do this change only in css

```
  #rule {
      border-top: 1px solid #000000;
      margin-top:25px;
    }
ul.dropdown {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

here is the https://jsfiddle.net/cfhu1hvy/ check i have made change only in css

Comment: The format looks good.  But I can't have the body wrapped in the header div.  Obviously I simplified the html, but there is a lot more to the the main body text.   I need to isolate the header_holder section by itself. Is there any to do this without touching the HTML?

Comment: I think i added this answer, check out the last 3 lines of css code

Comment: By adding the margin-top I was able to get the line below.  How about ID left20?  Any way to place a space between them without inserting the DIV for the left20? i.e. not changing the HTML.

Comment: in ul.dropdown add the code i have mentioned,check out

Comment: it does not work on Safari if I just make changes to CSS :(  Also it does not collapse gracefully on any browser with CSS changes only.

Comment: @Growtham I managed to make it work by using your idea on the CSS; simply remove the position:relative; on google-translate and change the display to inline-block; on header_right and it worked. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: are you ready for a challenge? :)  [Convert CSS Memu to Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325050/how-to-convert-pure-css-menu-for-mobile)   Really stuck on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to make it work by:

- Remove the position:relative; on #google-translate
- Change the display to "inline-block" instead of "inline" on #header_right
- Add "margin-top:15px;" to #rule