# Problems converting pure CSS responsive menu for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have existing pure CSS menu for the desktop which expands from left to right when hover.

```
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation"></a>
  <a href="#" title="Hide navigation"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown dropdown-vertical">
    <span class="clearfix">
        <li class="dir">ITEM 1
            <ul>
                <li class="dir">SUB ITEM 1
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">SUB ITEM 2
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dir"><a href="">ITEM 2</a>
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dir"><a href="/dev/tradeshows.htm">ITEM 3</a>
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dir">ITEM 4
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 5</a></li>
        <li class="dir">ITEM 6
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>          
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 6</a></li>
        <li class="dir">ITEM 7
            <ul>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ITEM 8</a></li>
            </span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  padding: 1.25em;
  /* 20 */
}

ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown li,
ul.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  zoom: 1;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
  float: none;
}

ul.dropdown ul ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 99%;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul.dropdown-vertical {
  width: 110px;
}

ul.dropdown-vertical ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 99%;
}

ul.dropdown-vertical li {
  float: none;
}

ul.dropdown {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0;
  border-color: #fff #d9d9d9 #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown a:link,
ul.dropdown a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}


/* -- level mark -- */

ul.dropdown ul {
  width: 110px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------/
 * @section     Support Class `dir`
 * @level sep   ul, .class
 */

ul.dropdown *.dir {
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-image: url(https://www.thesnowpros.org/DesktopModules/CISS.SideMenu/styles/BrandonTab/css/dropdown/themes/default/images/nav-arrow-right.png);
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* -- Components override -- */

ul.dropdown-horizontal ul *.dir {
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://www.thesnowpros.org/DesktopModules/CISS.SideMenu/styles/BrandonTab/css/dropdown/themes/default/images/nav-arrow-right.png);
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

I have tried to change it so that the left-to-right menu will become Accordion menu going down in mobile mode.

```
/* for mobile devices */

@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em)
/* 640 */

{
  html {
    font-size: 75%;
    /* 12 */
  }
  #nav > a {
    display: none;
    }
  #nav {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
  }
  #nav > a {
    width: 3.125em;
    /* 50 */
    height: 3.125em;
    /* 50 */
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
  }
  #nav > a:before,
  #nav > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    content: '';
  }
  #nav > a:after {
    top: 60%;
  }
  #nav:not(:target) > a:first-of-type,
  #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
  }
  /* first level */
  #nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  #nav:target > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #nav > ul > li > a {
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0.833em;
    /* 20 (24) */
  }
  #nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) > a {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc470d;
  }
  /* second level */
  #nav li ul {
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

I have tried to use [this](http://codepen.io/massiebn/pen/KrJvi) a base but was not able to make it work properly.

My attempt is shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2k50dkv/8/).  To see the mobile version, resize the window.   The issue is:

- all the menu and sub-menus expanded when click on the icon instead of showing when selected

I have tried many ways but can't seems to get it to work properly.  Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: It's helpful to provide the most minimal example possible -- that way we can jump right in without having to do too much puzzling. In this case, you can cut design stuff (colors, borders, fonts, etc), and merge a bunch of CSS (e.g. you provide some `ul.dropdown` styles at the top and some about half way down). There's no `ul.dropdown` that isn't also `ul.dropdown-vertical`, the `ul.dropdown-vertical` styles could be merged into `ul.dropdown` (maybe not on your site, but here); and you can cut the styles relating to `ul.dropdown-horizontal`.

Comment: And a little unasked for CSS advice ;) `*.dir` should probably be `.dir`, and all the `ul.something` styles will be processed faster by the browser if they're just `.something`.

Comment: @henry  Thank you for your comment.  The CSS is actually used for both vertical and horizontal menus. I copied and pasted in the fiddle for completeness sake.   Any advice is most welcomed.  I am a CSS novice.  So I need all the help I can get. :)  Now I am stuck with how to do the mobile menu

Comment: Completeness was def a reasonable thought, but in this case it just means you're asking us to do the work wading through extra code. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on how to write a question that'll encourage others to work on an answer. We'll get this figured out eventually!

Comment: For mobile design it is not recommended to have elements popping up horizontally, imagine the usability on a small device! Also for mobile, you can't rely on "hover", except maybe for all samsung note user...
What I recommend you is to check out Bootstraps navbar. When the screen size gets small, it completely hides the menu items and displays a vertical dropdown for navigation. Cheers!

Comment: @HanChe What I meant to say is like the Accordion menu. When one touch the item it will expand down.  I already have the desktop menu set up like this and it does go with the site.  I want to avoid getting a complete new menu system.  Having say that I will take a look at the Bootstraps navibar.

Comment: @henry, I have tried to do it and got 'pretty' close but still not quite yet.  Please have a look at the fiddle.  If you can help that will be great. Thanks.